# Update JPanel border if JSlider changes

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jslider

Can somebody tell me in general how I change some attributes of a `JPanel`/`TitledBorder` if I change a class variable through a `JSlider`?

e.g. I have the class variable "number" and change this var through a `stateChanged` event on the slider. Now I want to achieve that the value of the number is shown within a title border of the panel.

```
    panelX = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,0));
    panelX.setBorder(new TitledBorder("P0: X = "));
    frame.add(panelX);

    slider_x = new JSlider(0, 100);
    slider_x.addChangeListener(this);

    panelX.add(slider_x);

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    System.out.println(source);
    hasChanged = true;
    if(source instanceof JSlider) {
        update();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access the title border of the panel where the event firing slider is attached to?

Comment: You should set a new border for your panel with the new title

Comment: You need a reference to the original instance of `TitledBorder`, then you can use [`TitledBorder#setTitle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html#setTitle-java.lang.String-)

Comment: A really, really horrible way to do it might be to do something like `((JComponent)((JSlider)e.getSource()).getParent()).getBorder()`, but if that doesn't blow up in your face, then you are very, very lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the new border for your panel.

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    System.out.println(source);
    hasChanged = true;
    if(source instanceof JSlider) {
        panelX.setBorder(new TitledBorder("P0: X = " + ((JSlider) source).getValue());
        update();
    }
}
```